# javafx IllegalArguementException when popup is open and mouse is clicked on the background stage

Tags: javafx-2, tableview, type-mismatch, onmouseclick

on click of it i am launching a popup. Pop has a dynamically created stackpane with a tableview. If i double click a row in table or i enter esc its working fine.
Issue is when i click anywhere on the background stage it gives me following error. How to close the popup when i click on the stage from where the popup is launched. Please suggest.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1435)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3324)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3164)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3119)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1559)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2261)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Below is my code

```
public void trkTripNoBtnClick(ActionEvent ae){
    StackPane st = new StackPane();
    final TableView<GatePassDTO> tripListTableView = new TableView<GatePassDTO>();
    TableColumn<GatePassDTO,String> colTrkTripNo = new TableColumn<GatePassDTO,String>();
    TableColumn<GatePassDTO,Date> colGatePassDttm = new TableColumn<GatePassDTO,Date>();
    TableColumn<GatePassDTO,String> colTruckNo = new TableColumn<GatePassDTO,String>();
    TableColumn<GatePassDTO,String> colBat = new TableColumn<GatePassDTO,String>();
    colTrkTripNo.setText("Trip No");
    colTrkTripNo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GatePassDTO,String>("tourPlnNo"));
    colGatePassDttm.setText("Gate Pass Dttm");
    colGatePassDttm.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GatePassDTO,Date>("gatePassDttm"));
    colTruckNo.setText("Truck");
    colTruckNo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GatePassDTO,String>("haulPmNo"));
    colBat.setText("BAT ID");
    colBat.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GatePassDTO,String>("batId"));
    List<GatePassDTO> tripsList = GateIn.getGatePassReference().gateIn_tourPlnNoLookUp(1);
    tripListTableView.getColumns().addAll(colTrkTripNo,colGatePassDttm,colTruckNo,colBat);
    tripListTableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(tripsList));
    final Popup popup = new Popup(); 
    popup.setX(txtTrkTripNo.getLayoutX()); 
    popup.setY(txtTrkTripNo.getLayoutY()+txtTrkTripNo.getHeight()+30);

    colTrkTripNo.prefWidthProperty().bind(tripListTableView.widthProperty().multiply(0.20));
    colGatePassDttm.prefWidthProperty().bind(tripListTableView.widthProperty().multiply(0.45));
    colTruckNo.prefWidthProperty().bind(tripListTableView.widthProperty().multiply(0.15));
    colBat.prefWidthProperty().bind(tripListTableView.widthProperty().multiply(0.20));
    tripListTableView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            if(t.getClickCount() == 2 && tripListTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() !=null){
                GatePassDTO g = tripListTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                popup.hide();
                txtTrkTripNo.setText(g.getTourPlnNo());
                getTripDetails(txtTrkTripNo.getText());
            }
        }   
    });
    tripListTableView.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            if(t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE)
                popup.hide();
        }

    });
    /*Label lblFind = new Label("Find");
    TextField txtfind = new TextField();
    st.getChildren().add(lblFind);
    st.getChildren().add(txtfind);*/
    st.getChildren().add(tripListTableView);
    VBox v = new VBox(5);
    v.getChildren().addAll(st);
    popup.getContent().addAll(v);       
    popup.show(GateIn.primaryStage);    
}
```

Comment: can you show code ?? can you put mouse event only on table or complete stage ??

Comment: @Anshul Parashar added code in my question.

Comment: i am giving a answer try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to check focus property for stage...

try this its worked

```
stage.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>
    () {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
           if(t1==false)
           {
               System.out.println("focus losted");
               btn.getScene().getWindow().hide();
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi mouse click on table is working perfectly. Issue is when i click outside of popup when popup is open

Comment: @Sil i am edited above answer...actually issue is not in your code you need to lock your pop up window...i.e when you click on outside the pop up its not work and its done by modality

Comment: like in ms word when we click on find pop up- is open but when click on outside its not working till pop up is not close

Comment: but i want the pop up to be closed when click on outside.

Comment: @Sil i am edited answer...and you need to done this with focusproperty() try code its worked...here

Comment: Hi, listener on focusedProperty works when i launch popup on new stage. Its not working when show the popup on primary stage, like below 
`Pagination pagination = PaginatedTableView.getPaginatedTableView(tripListTableView, tripsList);
  popup.getContent().addAll(pagination);     
  popup.show(GateIn.primaryStage);` 
It still gives same IllegalArgumentException